# Test Mailgun incoming emails locally

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mailgun

I'm implementing feature of getting Incoming Emails from Mailgun. I created action:

```
[Route("incoming-email/notify")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> NotifyIncomingEmail([FromForm] CreateIncomingEmailCmd cmd)
{ ... }
```

and want to debug it locally (send to localhost) to check if params are mapped correctly.

So, for example if I send via Postman as x-www-form-urlencoded param `body-html` then it isn't mapped to my property `BodyHtml` of `CreateIncomingEmailCmd` class and `[JsonProperty("body-html")]` didn't help.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [ModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinderattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) attribute to specify the name of the property like below:

```
public class CreateIncomingEmailCmd
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "body-plain")]
    public string BodyPlain { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "body-html")]
    public string BodyHtml { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My class `CreateIncomingEmailCmd` is in separate project (.NET Standard) so I can't use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace here.